# How do I sum a numpy array of size (m*n,) in groups of m?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have `a` where `a.shape` is `(m*n,)`, how do I create a new array that comprises the `m` sums of each group of `n` elements *efficiently*?

The best I came up with is:

```
a.reshape((m, n)).sum(axis=1)
```

but this creates an extra new array.

Comment: What do you mean by  `(mn,)`? Is that a length-one tuple containing only a variable called `mn`? If not, what do you mean? If so, what are `m` and `n`?

Comment: @KSFT: Just multiplication; I'll make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another trick, a variant on `cumsum`, `reduceat`.  In this case

```
np.add.reduceat(a, np.arange(0,m*n,n))
```

For `m,n=100,10`, it is 2x as fast as `x.reshape((m,n)).sum(axis=1)`.

I haven't used it much, so it took a bit of digging to find in the documentation.

Comment: +1 Wow, I never heard about `reduceat`! This might be useful to replace some ugly hacks I did with cumsum in the past.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is nothing wrong with using `reshape` and then taking the sum of the rows, I cannot think of anything faster. According to the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), `reshape` should (if possible) return a view on the original array, so no large amount of data is copied. When a view is created, numpy only creates a new header with different strides and shape, with a pointer into the data of the original array. This should cost constant time and memory, independent of the array size.

```
In [23]: x = np.arange(12)

In [24]: y = x.reshape((3, 4))

In [25]: y
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [26]: y.base is x  # check if it is a view
Out[26]: True
```

Comment: Ah!  Did not know it yields a view!

Comment: Probably true for standard arrays, since for large arrays you will be accessing adjacent elements in memory, which is better for caching. But try for yourself in ipython, by creating `x = np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000,1000)` and doing a `timeit x.sum(axis=0)` and similar for `axis=1`. On my machine, the second is 25% faster. This will probably depend on the specific machine, array sizes and if your array uses C-style or Fortran-style memory layout.